# How to import Listviewanimation to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview

Can someone give me a somewhat detailed step by step of how to import this library into an eclipse android project. I have imported many in the past, but they each seem to have different caveats to them and I can't figure this one out.

Here is the link to the main page of the library. I am trying to import lib-manipulation

> http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/

currently when I import it there are errors in the project specifically in the manifest where it says

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'allowBackup' in package android'
```

next to:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true">
    <activity android:name="com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.swipedismiss.SwipeTouchListenerTestActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.dragdrop.DynamicListViewTestActivity" />
</application>
```

It says on their page you need nineoldandroids but I already have that imported into my main project. When I import it (again the library shows errors at this point) I get the red exclamation point and sure enough there is a dependency issue which says the binary for the library cannot be found. I'd really like to use this library for my current project and those in the future. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: have u import this project in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse , Right click your project in the package explorer view (left side pane) and click on **Properties** and check Your **Build Target** (under **Android** Tab), is it pointing to the minimum SDK defined in the AndroidManifest.xml